# Automatically checking for accidental spaces in macros?

Tags: macros, spacing

It is easy to forget a `\relax` or `%` at the line end of commands in the body of macros. For example, in writing

```
\def\myMacro{
  \invokeX
  \invokeY{}
  \invokeZ
}
```

You must add a space swallower at the end of the first and third line, but not at the end of the second, fourth and fifth lines.

A simple global search/replace of `{$` by `{%` will fix omissions such as that of the first line, and is not likely to add redundant swallowers. But, a global search/replace of `}$` by `}%` will also add a percent after the fifth line.

For the benefit of Google search visitors, let me write the `vi` commands for these searches:

```
:%s/{$/{%/
:%s/}$/}%/
```

But as I mention, these are not perfect, and may not take care of other tricky cases.

So, my question is: **Can you do better?** Perhaps there is a clever redefinition of `\def` that would eliminate the need for these ugly additions, or perhaps there is some other automatic mechanism that would warn against such potential bugs?

Comment: You should mentioned that `$` is the end-of-line marker in regular expressions used for the search&replace. Otherwise some people will wonder what you mean with replacing `{$` with `{%`.

Comment: I edited your question, because your original example with `\invokeM1` is equivalent to `\invokeM 1` (digits cannot be part of the macro name (with the default catcodes)) and therefore all lines would need to eat spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote some code to check a chunk of code. It counts how many spaces and how many spaces+end-line-characters appear in the argument of `\cnel`, and displays it to the terminal. It also runs the code: this way, it shouldn't be too disruptive.

```
% Should print 1 and 4.
\cnel{
  \def\foo{b ar
  }
}

% Just to stop the run (press <enter>)
\read-1 to\dummy

% Should print 0 and 0, because there is no space nor end-of-line.
\cnel{%
  \show\foo
}
```

The trick is to

- use `\scantokens` to read the argument with various catcode setups for the end-of-line character: either ignored or space. We first need to read it with catcode other because "ignored" it would disappear, and "space", it would become indistinguishable from a true space.
- use `\lowercase` to convert spaces to some other *character* (namely `^^S`), then `\detokenize`, and search for the *string* `^^S`. (That string is itself produced by detokenizing a lowercase space.)

.

```
% `cnel` = `check if no end-line`.
%
\catcode`\@=11\relax
\newcount\cnel@count


\def\cnel{%
  \begingroup%
  \catcode\endlinechar=12\relax%
  \cnel@aux%
}
\newcommand{\cnel@aux}[2][\^^S]{%
  % Set spaces to lowercase to the first, optional, argument (default ^^S).
  \lccode`\ `#1%
  % First we count the number of spaces with a setting in which 
  % the end-line character is ignored. Then we count it after setting
  % it to be a space instead.
  \typeout{}%
  \typeout{First, we ignore end-of-line characters.}%
  \catcode\endlinechar=9\relax%
  \scantokens{\cnel@count@spaces{#2}}%
  \typeout{}%
  \typeout{Then, they are counted as spaces.}%
  \catcode\endlinechar=10\relax%
  \scantokens{\cnel@count@spaces{#2}}%
  % To execute the code, we keep this endline=space setting.
  \scantokens{\gdef\cnel@gtmp{#2}}%
  \endgroup%
  \cnel@gtmp%
}

\newcommand{\cnel@count@spaces}[1]{%
  \cnel@count0\relax%
  \lowercase{\expandafter\cnel@w\detokenize{. .#1 }\relax%
    \typeout{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  }%
  \typeout{Number of space(s): \the\cnel@count.}%
}
\def\cnel@w.#1.{%
  \def\cnel@w@aux##1#1##2\relax{%
    \ifempty@nTF{##2}{}{%
      \advance \cnel@count by 1\relax%
      \cnel@w@aux##2\relax%
    }%
  }%
  \cnel@w@aux%
}
\def\ifempty@nTF#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter a\detokenize{#1}a%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
  \else%
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
  \fi%
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I just cannot tell you how much I appreciate this. I think this should be packaged and advertised!

Comment: @Yossi: I'll try to understand the code again this or next week-end, and perhaps turn it into an environment, and think a bit more about catcodes.

Comment: @Bruno: I know this may be very time consuming. Should you decide to to do this, I trust the community will be very grateful.

Comment: @Yossi: it's not that time consuming. I just can't figure out a good interface. And I can't remember why I treated spaces and end nf line character differently above. If you have any clue, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: @Yossi: I'm getting into unforseenly busy times, unfortunately. And my quick attempt at packaging tonight didn't work. So that will happen later. Sorry. --- About why eol are treated specially: the idea is that the user might want to ignore spaces which appear in the middle of the line, because those are more often intentional. Also I need to implement ignoring spaces outside braces.

Comment: @Bruno: I thought of adding a case study showing how I used this to debug my `bashful` package, but I was to busy to release the new changes, and I had to many changes waiting on the pipeline.

Comment: @Yossi: I've finally written something. Is it ok if it can only check whole files, rather than pieces?

Comment: @Bruno: I see the main application in hunting for mysterious spaces that pop into macros. So, if you wish to do a divide and conquer in trying to find the space, file level granularity is going to make it difficult.

Comment: @Yossi. Thanks for your feedback. I just put the package [debugspaces online](http://users.aims.ac.za/~bruno/LaTeX/debugspaces/). It would be great to know if you think that the commands I define there are enough. Then I'll submit it to CTAN.

Answer (score 5):

ConTeXt provides `\starttexdefinition` ... `\stoptexdefinition` environment that does exactly that. Using that you can write your command as:

```
\starttexdefinition myMacro
  \invokeX
  \invokeY{}
  \invokeZ
\stoptexdefinition
```

I believe that LaTeX3 also provides a similar syntax.

Comment: Thanks Atidya. I applied Lev's correction to your answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

For LaTeX, using the `expl3` package:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\myMacro{
  \invokeX
  \invokeY{}
  \invokeZ
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

or even

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def \myMacro {
  \invokeX
  \invokeY { }
  \invokeZ
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: You could add that when the `ExplSyntax` is on, spaces are ignored, the end of line character is a space, `~` is a genuine space, and `:` and `_` are letters (usable in macro names). (Am I missing something?)